# 線分探索でエラーが出る原因

Tags: python, xcode, visual-studio

```
def LinearSearch(N, a):
n = len(N)
for i in range(n):
    if N[i] == a:
        return True

    else:
        return False

N = [13, 16, 23, 45, 54, 58, 76, 91]
a = 76

ans = LinearSearch(N, a)
print(ans)
```

結果が何故かfalseになってしまいます、
for文とif文の組み合わせが良くないのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: タグに [xcode] と [visual-studio] とありますが、どちらをお使いになったのでしょうか。Python のバージョンやお使いの IDE のバージョンなどの情報を、タグではなく質問文として追記して頂けると幸いです。

Comment: こちらのコードをそのままコピペして動かすと、インデントがおかしいためエラーになります。おそらくコードブロックとして装飾する際にずれてしまったのだと思います。コードを再度ペーストし、範囲選択した上でエディタ上部の `{}` をクリックすると自動的にコードブロックとして整形できますので、ご利用ください。

Comment: おそらく線分探索ではなく線形探索だと思うのですが、あっていますでしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、関数名も`LinearSearch`ですし、コード内容も線形探索(のちょっとミス版)なんで、確かめるまでもなく「線形探索」のことだとしてもいいのではないでしょうか?

Comment: @OOPer それはそうなのですが、僕の知らない界隈で線分探索と言っているのかもしれないなと思いまして……（「線分探索」でググると linear search とは関係なさそうな「線分探索」がたくさんひっかかって、調べられなかったのです）。回答を作るためでなく、タイトルを直してもよいか確認するためのコメントでした。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、どこに慎重になるべきかと言うのはあれこれ議論しても仕方ないのでもう置きますが、3連続でのコメントで、「些細な言葉の間違いも許さないぞ」なんて意図に取られないかと心配になったもので。コメントとほぼ同時に回答をつけておられるので、杞憂だったかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

推測ですが、wakewakameman さんは、以下の様に書こうと思ったのではないでしょうか。

```
def LinearSearch(N, a):
  n = len(N)
  for i in range(n):
    if N[i] == a:
        return True
  else:
    return False
```

# この書き方が間違いというわけでもありませんけれども

Comment: for: else:ってあるんですね。勉強になります。

Answer (score 1):

おそらくpythonをアルゴリズム学習に使用していると推察されますが、python的な書き方を提示しておきます。

```
N = [13, 16, 23, 45, 54, 58, 76, 91] #Nは自然数を示すのが通例なので、この名付けは推奨しない
a = 76
```

として

```
a in N
```

と記述すれば、求める結果が得られます。
設問者が提示したコードの流れは、
N[0]=13は76ではないのでN[0]==76はFalse、よってelse句以降の文が実行される。
return Falseで関数LinearSearchを抜けるためforループからも脱出し、そのままFalseとなる。

Answer (score 0):

> for文とif文の組み合わせが良くないのでしょうか。

そう思います。for文内の最初の`13`を比較する際に、偽となるため、`False`がリターンされ、for文を抜けています。1つの要素しか比較されていません。

例えば、以下のように、for文内は、真の場合のみ`True`を返却し、for文を終了した場合は、`False`を返却するば良いと思います。

いずれにしても、お使いの開発環境で、Pythonをデバッグできるようになると、ご自身で現象の把握とバグの修正ができると思います。

```
def LinearSearch(N, a):
    n = len(N)
    for i in range(n):
        if N[i] == a:
            return True
    return False


N = [13, 16, 23, 45, 54, 58, 76, 91]
a = 76

ans = LinearSearch(N, a)
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

`LinearSearch` 関数内のループでは、まず最初の要素 `N[0]` と `a` とを比較することになりますが、ここで `N[0]` と `a` が等しくなかったら即座に `return False` してしまいます。これがバグの原因です。

実際にはそうではなく、全ての要素と比較した上でどれとも等しくなかったら `return False` する、というようになるはずです。

以下にサンプルコードを書きましたので、必要に応じてご利用ください（マウスカーソルを重ねると表示されます）。

> def LinearSearch(N, a):
>      n = len(N)
>      for i in range(n):
>          if N[i] == a:
>              return True
>      return False